# Error deploying Shopify app on Heroku - TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@shopify/app-bridge-types'

Tags: shopify-app, remix.run, shopify-app-bridge

I am encountering an issue when deploying my app on Heroku. Despite following all the steps outlined in the provided URLs, I am facing the following error:

```
TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@shopify/app-bridge-types'.
The file is in the program because:
Entry point of type library '@shopify/app-bridge-types' specified in compilerOptions
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Create App Steps: https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/getting-started/create

Deploy Steps: https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/deployment/web

I have already installed app-bridge-types, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

App Bridge dependency should not be a dev dependency.
Check the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-remix/issues/489